# Extend VScode color picker to Rmarkdown .Rmd

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VScode to write R scripts and I appreciate the ability of having a color picker on the .R file I am working on (image below).

[image]

However, when I am using an Rmarkdown file in VScode, I dont get to see the color picker even though I am writing withing an R code block ```{R} ... ```. Is there a way to make the color picker available to my .Rmd files in VScode?

[image]